# Make Androidplot charts to display values for every key point on a graph

Tags: android, androidplot

I am trying to make androidplot graphs display tiny texts with corresponding values for every key point on a graph, but I am completely lost how to achieve that.

By key points I mean dots outline with circles in this file https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9443658/varia/Timeseries.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just FYI, as of version 0.5.1 this functionality is available via the LineAndPointFormatter.  If the paint param associated with point labels is not null or transparent, you'll see values printed above each point.

Here's a [link to the blog post](http://androidplot.com/point-labeling-tools-in-0-5-1/) with details.

Comment: Great, does 0.5.1 support zooming and panning out of the box also?

Comment: There havent been any added featured related to panning / zooming.